# UI Issue when dynamically binding a list of objects to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-interface, datagrid

```
class ContainingObject
{
    private ContainedObject objContained;

    public int ContainingObjectID { get; set; }
    public ContainedObject Obj { get { return objContained; } }

    // Methods that initalize contained objects and such <here>
}

class ContainedObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}

// Binding Code
List<ContainingObject> lstContainingObjects = new List<ContainingObject>();
// Code to Populate List <here>
dtgrdTheDataGrid.ItemsSource = lstContainingObjects;
```

When the list is bound to the datagrid it shows only the following columns; `ContainingObjectID` and `Obj`.

1. How do I, without modifying the (edit:XAML) and creating properties for each member within a `ContainedObject` in the `ContainingObject` itself, get the datagrid to show the following columns; `ContainingObjectID`, `Obj`, `ID`, `Height`, `Width`?
2. What can I do to get the `Obj` (it returns a `ContainedObject`) column to actually display something in each row's cell?

Comment: what does "without modifying the WPF" specify? do you mean XAML?

Comment: Yeah sorry that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of a `DataGrid` is to AutoGenerateColumns, which means it will look at your objects and create a column for each public property on the object.

To change this behavior, you can set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, and manually add your own Columns to the DataGrid. This would be what I recommend.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgrdTheDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>        
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ContainingObjectId" Binding="{Binding ContainingObjectID }" />      
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ContainedObject">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Whatever you want here" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ContainedObjectId" Binding="{Binding ContainedObject.Id}" />  
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding ContainedObject.Height}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding ContainedObject.Width}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you do not want to build your own columns, you can expand your `ContainingObject` class to include public properties for the `ContainedObject` properties. To display something else in the `Obj` column, overwrite the `.ToString()` method of `ContainedObject`, since WPF will by default write the `.ToString()` method of any class it doesn't know how to draw in the UI.

```
class ContainingObject
{
    private ContainedObject objContained;

    public int ContainingObjectID { get; set; }
    public ContainedObject Obj { get { return objContained; } }

    // Of course, you should include a check for if objContained is null
    public int ContainedObjectId { get { return objContained.Id; } }
    public int ContainedObjectHeight { get { return objContained.Height; } }
    public int ContainedObjectWidth { get { return objContained.Width; } }

}

class ContainedObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
        // Return whatever you want here
        return string.format("Contained object: {0}", ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift responce. I would like to keep the default behavior to auto generate the columns enabled. Is there some way to have the 'DataGrid' generate the columns from the public properties located within the 'ContainedObject'? I've also overrode the 'ContainedObject' ToString function and it still displays nothing within the cell.

Comment: @layern9ne The DataGrid was only designed to read properties directly on the data object itself, not any sub properties. If you want a different behavior you'll have to overwrite the DataGrid to implement your own logic.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve the issue of not being able to see anything in the `Obj` column cells by changing the `column.IsReadOnly` to true.